# What are the reasons someone would choose Java over other technologies for desktop applications? GUI's in particular

Tags: java, user-interface

Why would someone choose Java to create desktop applications (GUI's to be more specific) ? The reason I'm asking is that there are obvious and better choices. For windows there's C# and .NET framework, for mac there's Objective-C and the Cocoa framework and for cross platform compatibility there's Qt and C++ (also mono).

What are the reasons someone would discard the above choices and go with Java ? Besides the fact that someone "knows only Java", I'm interested in real reasons, benefits and when would Java be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is the most portable / platform independent way of implementing desktop applications with GUIs.

- C# and .NET are Windows specific.
- Received wisdom Mono isn't really good enough yet.
- Objective-C and the Cocoa are thoroughly Mac specific.
- Qt and C++ code is portable in theory, but it requires a lot more care / attention to detail to achieve portability in practice.  (Plus, C++ is a non-managed language so you have memory management and related stability issues to deal with.)

For many applications a potentially more portable solution is to implement the GUI in a web browser.  Certainly, this avoids the problem of installing applications on the desktop.  However, you then have to contend with:

- people / organizations that don't update their browser platform,
- web browsers incompatibilities and bugs,
- security sandboxes,
- the problem of implementing browser plugins / extensions for multiple browsers, and
- installing said plugins / extensions.

Comment: "most"? I don't think so. There is tcl/tk and python/wxpyton just to name two of many.

Answer (score 6):

Portability would be one reason. You can write your code in Java and run it on any platform with a JRE.

That means it will run under Linux, AIX, HPUX, Solaris, OS X, Windows, OS/400 (or whatever it's called nowadays) and even z/OS. None of the other solutions you mentioned have quite that spread.

Mono notwithstanding, C# is pretty much used for Windows in the vast majority of cases. Objective C, while available elsewhere, is used mainly for the Apple universe.

Having said that, since the bulk of my work is Windows-based, I'm tending more towards C# since it's currently a more marketable skill, and it does everything that Java does for me.

Comment: There are other languages with better "write once, run anywhere" behavior than java. Java isn't quite as good in this regard as it advertises to be.

Comment: @Bryan, better in what way exactly? Are you claiming that these other languages run on _more_ platforms? That their behaviour is more _consistent_ across platforms? I have a hard time believing that the languages I know of (Python, Perl et al) would meet either of those criteria of "better" but I'm open to being educated.

Comment: @paxidiablo: There are languages which run on more desktop platforms I believe. And I wasn't talking about consistent *behavior*, I was talking about being able to run *at all*. Just a couple weeks ago someone submitted a response to a programming challenge as part of our hiring process and it only ran on windows and the mac, despite being written in Java.  I could have solved that problem with Tcl/Tk and it would have run on pretty much every desktop system that is running today (but, no, it wouldn't run on a phone)

Comment: Wow, that must have been one badly written piece of Java. It's hard to imagine that even being possible without resorting to JNI. You might have troubles getting TCL running at the _other_ end of that scale as well (System z) - I know it runs under zLinux but I've never seen it under USS (z/OS UNIX System Services) on the mainframe. I may be wrong however, it wouldn't be the first time :-)

Answer (score 3):

The choices you list are only “better” given a list of specific requirements. In general the main one is I can use language X because I’m only targeting one platform. While C# may be better for windows it is not as good as Java if you need to run your code across multiple platforms. Java is the only mainstream way to write cross platform GUI’s with the possible exception of Mono that frees you from the requirements of memory management. Java is also the only option for creating a binary that can run on multiple platforms. While QT will allow you to create GUI’s for multiple platforms you will have to do a custom build for each platform. Although a GUI is an important part of many applications it is generally not the only part. Out of all the languages you have listed Java has the most third party libraries of any. This means you can write both your user interface and your backend code in one language to run on multiple platforms. If you wish to move your application from a desktop GUI to a web application at a future date this will be easier to do with a well architected Java solution then with a QT application written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You should code it in java if you want portability. Java runs on every desktop OS that matters.

C# is in my opinion a better candidate if your application is to be a Windows-only one. The gui editor is a breeze to work with compared to making it from scratch in say Swing.

Objective-C is a Apple thing, and along with Qt/C++ it is in theory portable, but you will still have to work your way through segfaults and potential memory leaks. Java requires no source code changes to work on say Linux or Mac, even though you only code on Windows.

Javas most compelling feature is the tools you can use, not to mention the libraries for virtually anything. You get a lot of freedom in choice of tools. If you like Qt you can also find java bindings for it, I recall it's called Qt/Jambi.

Alternatively you can code the backend in C++/Mono/Objective-C and have the frontend done in java. That way at least your gui is easily ported.

Answer (score 1):

I like Java because I can create a desktop application, and with literally 3 lines of code, I can deploy it to the web as an applet. So portability between operating systems is great, but also the ability to easily deploy it to the web is a plus.

Answer (score -1):

Portability is a bit oversold. It's nice, but unlikely to be a killer feature of your app.

Why go with Java? Because Eclipse is one of the greatest apps ever made. And as Eclipse is also a platform, you can leverage a whole bunch of it for building your own apps too.